# Elasticsearch Date Histogram with a Point in Time count of documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am attempting to create a date histogram showing the number of employees on a monthly basis.

Employee mapping looks something like this:

```
{
    "number": 1234,
    "firstName": "Chris",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "employmentDates: [
        {
            "startDate": "2014-10-03T06:00:00Z",
            "endDate": "2017-11-04T06:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "lastPaidOnDate": "2017-11-10T06:00:00Z",
    ....
}
```

Given a start end scenario like this (for three employees):

```
|----------------|
       |-----------------------------|
  |---|    |---------------------|
 ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
```

I would expect the histogram to be similar to this:

```
"aggregations": {
    "employees_per_month": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key_as_string": "2017-01-01",
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "2017-02-01",
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "2017-03-01",
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "2017-04-01",
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "2017-05-01",
                "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
                "key_as_string": "2017-06-01",
                "doc_count": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It seems like I need to have a sub-aggregation on a scripted field, but I'm not sure where to start.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's can be done by using DateHistogram. But I'm suggesting a a simple approach. You will have to run the query every time for one specific month:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "bool_agg": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "employmentDates.startDate": {
                  "lt": "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "employmentDates.endDate": {
                  "gte": "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "distinct_agg": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "number"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- **bool_agg**: using [Filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) to filter only employment in November
- **distinct_agg**: using [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) to count, by unique field `number`, the total employees

Pay attention that if `employmentDates` would contain more then one record, e.g:

```
"employmentDates: [
   {
      "startDate": "2014-10-03T06:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2017-11-04T06:00:00Z"
   }
   {
      "startDate": "2018-03-03T06:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2018-07-04T06:00:00Z"
   }
```

You will must go nested with [Nested Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/nested.html), example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971933/extract-record-from-multiple-arrays-based-on-a-filter/47000112#47000112).
And update the query to:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "nested_agg": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "employmentDates"
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "bool_agg": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "employmentDates.startDate": {
                      "lt": "2017-12-01T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "employmentDates.endDate": {
                      "gte": "2017-11-01T00:00:00Z"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "comment_to_issue": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggregations": {
                "distinct_agg": {
                  "cardinality": {
                    "field": "number"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```